# flat category/product table error in Magento

Tags: magento, flat

After a few minutes on the site, we get the following error while loading a product page

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition() in
>   [...]/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 318

I have done lots of research but don't seem to be able to fix it.

It seems to happen only when the user is idle on the site for a few minutes.

The same product page works fine if I re-enter the website.

Comment: can put excpetion.log file from var/log/ to question

Comment: the exceptions log file has over 3k lines. is there anything specific you want me to post from that file?

Comment: Is there any module installed that works on ajax or something related to categories?

Comment: delete this file.. then try reindexing  again.. and this time get excpeioon log andn  put

Comment: if you can search the coded files, find the file where the function getProductsPosition() is being called. paste the code here.

Comment: So far i found it in a helper file associated with INCHOO NexPrev plugin.  I have disabled this now in the Configuration/System/Advance area in the back-end. will test to see if the issue is resolved.  We dont need this feature anyways.

Comment: I confirm I got the same issue with the Inchoo Extension. Deactivating it, resolve the issue

Comment: An issue was logged here. Please respond or confirm the issue! via this link https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_Prevnext/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Please monitor this issue for a fix ....

https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_Prevnext/issues/2

and here is the pull request.

https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_Prevnext/pull/3

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this by disabling flat catalog if you do not nessicarily need it:

1. System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Category: No
2. System > Index Management: reindex all
3. System > Cache Management: flush cache